# How to find common part among all items in the string list?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QStringList that holds filenames. What would be the correct way to find their common root, that is, their common left part?

I am writing on c++ and use Qt.

Comment: Do all strings contain the same root?

Comment: For the most part, they will

Comment: Well, what if they don't? Which "root" do you want to find then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

traverse QStringList, comparing root and each string :

```
QString root(QString &a, QString &b)
{
    QString str;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); ++i) {
        if(a.at(i) == b.at(i))str.push_back(a.at(i));
        else break;
    }
    return str;
}

QString dosth(QStringList &list)
{
    QString str;
    if(list.isEmpty()) return str;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
        str = root(str, list.at(i));
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to do a minor change. In `dosth`, before the for loop: `str = list[0]; if(list.size() == 1) return str;` And changed the foor loop variable, from `i = 0` to `i = 1`. Also, since the list isn't modified, in both functions I changed the parameters to `const`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an algorithm:

- Take the first string as **root**.
- For each **item** in the **list**

  - If **root** is longer than **item**

    - **root**.[truncate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#truncate)(**item**.length());
  - For each index **i** in **root**

    - If **root** [ **i** ] does not match **item** [ **i** ]

      - **root**.[truncate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#truncate)( **i** );

Edit: some code that I haven't tested but "should" work.

c++03 code:

```
QString find_root(const QStringList& list)
{
    QString root = list.front();
    for(QStringList::const_iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (root.length() > it->length())
        {
            root.truncate(it->length());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < root.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (root.at(i) != it->at(i))
            {
                root.truncate(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

c++11 code:

```
QString find_root(const QStringList& list)
{
    QString root = list.front();
    for(const auto& item : list)
    {
        if (root.length() > item.length())
        {
            root.truncate(item.length());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < root.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (root[i] != item[i])
            {
                root.truncate(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

Comment: I like the elegance! Note that this first goes through the whole first string redundantly before starting the real work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready solution, but writing new code is just 5 minutes:

```c
int commonBeginningLength(const QString &a, const QString &b) {
    int maxLen = qMin(a.length(), b.length());
    int i=0;
    for(int i=0; i<maxLen; ++i)
        if (a.at(i)!=b.at(i))
            break;
    return i;
}

QString comonBegining(const QStringList &list) {
    if (list.isEmpty())
       return QString();
    QString result(list.front());
    for(int i=1; i<list.count(); ++i) {
        result = result.left(commonBeginningLength(result, list.at(i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```